# Rails 3 show erros in a JSON request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to show the errors that can occur by uploading a file (file name, size).
I am using [ad adapted version of Jquery Fiel Upload for Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)
I tried to modify this code cut-off but I could not.

```
else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

I have following validations and I want json to write when an error occured, so something like this:

```
else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity, error:"Error!" }
end
```

(it doenst work) and I need a specification of an error, that is written in a validation :message

my validations:

```
validates :upload_file_name,  :presence   => true,
                                :format     =>{:with => %r{\.(cel)$}i}

  validates_uniqueness_of :upload_file_name, :message => "File with this name is already in the database"

  validates :upload_file_size,  :inclusion  => {:in =>10.megabytes..20.megabytes}, :message =>"Too big or too small"

  def to_jq_upload
  {
      "name" => read_attribute(:upload_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
      "url" => upload.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => upload_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
  }
  end

end
```

and the only javascript I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function () {
      // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
      $('#fileupload').fileupload();
      // 
      // Load existing files:
      $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
        var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload'), 
          template;
        fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
        console.log(files);
        template = fu._renderDownload(files)
          .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
        // Force reflow:
        fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
          template[0].offsetWidth;
        template.addClass('in');
        $('#loading').remove();
      });

  });
</script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure i understand your question well, but if you need to have your error messages associated to the `'error'` key in your json response, you can do this:

```
render json: {error: @json.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

Comment: Yes, you got me right.
The only problem in your solution ist that I get an error-text : Internal Server Error
and not what stands in my validation messages. And in terminal I get such an error:NoMethodError(undefined method "errors" for nil:Class in controllers/uploads_controller.rb in 'create'

Comment: and using  
    render json: {error: @upload.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity  shows no error messages at all

Comment: format.json { render json: => [{:error=> @upload.errors.full_messages }] } using this shows the validation message but I need the status: to be there as well